# Ubuntu 14.04 error opening package list

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, package

My self naitik joshi. I stuck with one major problem on ubuntu 14.04

When i run apt-get command in terminal it says:

**Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fIN
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.**

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

-Naitik

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Also please can you share the reason of above error,if possible ?

Comment: This generally happens between the translation file if you change server to get the dist files like for e.g I am from nepal and i take translations file from us server like interrupting the updating of one server at middle

Answer (score -1):

Open your terminal run the command `wget https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8850924/fixpackage`

```
chmod +x ./fixpackage
sudo ./fixpackage
```

This would generally install the fresh broken package for you and its working .